# Filtering a Lookup field using REST not working in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, rest

I'm trying to filter a column of type lookup from a list using this method.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Collections()?$expand=Departments&$filter=Departments/Title eq 'Sales'
```

And its outputting the following error:

```
<message xml:lang="en-US">No property 'Title' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' at position 12.</message>
```

And found out that below does work in displaying the departments title, through selecting, meaning title does exist.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Collections()?$expand=Departments&$select= Departments/Title
```

Am I missing something to be able to filter from a multiple lookup column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is by design. I can reproduce it if the lookup field can contain multiple references. If it is single lookup column, there is no error.