# Filtering Data on the results array Expanding a deffered uri

Tags: rest, filter

```
 http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/abcList?$select=ab/Title&$expand=ab
```

This is my request. I am getting expanded results of ab in an "results" array Like this :

```
"ab": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {...},
              "Title": "value1"
            }
            {
              "__metadata": {...},
              "Title": "value2"
            }
            {
              "__metadata": {...},
              "Title": "value1"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Now I want to filter it out according to ab/Title eq 'value1'

like this : `http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/abcList?$select=ab/Title&$expand=ab&$filter=ab/Title eq 'value1'`

But I am getting following Error --

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "No property 'Title' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=myToken]]' at position 8."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any help from my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... According to your response if we enable multiple selection in sharepoint level then can we do $filter operation on Multivalued look up column?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Markets": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {...},
              "Title": "Netherlands"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Above response seems to me that your lookup column is allowing multiple values. Unfortunately `$filter` is not supported on multi-valued lookup columns. It will not work unless you disable multiple selection in your lookup column.

*[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx)* reference reads

> Because multi-value lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple
>   values, there is no way to query for them (for example, the equivalent
>   of an Includes element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

Also have a look

- [Filtering a Lookup field using REST not working in Sharepoint
  2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140177/filtering-a-lookup-field-using-rest-not-working-in-sharepoint-2010)
- [How can I filter based on Choice fields when using ListData.svc in
  SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/how-can-i-filter-based-on-choice-fields-when-using-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-20)

Comment: first link idoesnt work